# NonConcreteBooleanIndexError fix with jax.numpy.where() in Python

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, jax

I am running a simple [demo example](https://github.com/google/lightweight_mmm/blob/main/examples/simple_end_to_end_demo.ipynb) of the lightweightMMM. I have used the lambda function for scaling, as follows:

```
media_data_train_a = media_data[:split_point, :]
lambda_operation = lambda x: jnp.mean(x[x > 0])
media_scaler = preprocessing.CustomScaler(divide_operation=lambda_operation)
media_data_train = np.array(media_scaler.fit_transform(media_data_train_a))
```

I have tried the same code with the example data, there it works just fine. However, when i tried it on my own dataset, i get following error when executing the last line:

`NonConcreteBooleanIndexError: Array boolean indices must be concrete; got ShapedArray(bool[41]) See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.NonConcreteBooleanIndexError`

Any ides what could be the reason that my data returns this error?

Both dataset are a numpy array. I also read the suggested [jax.doc](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.NonConcreteBooleanIndexError) and believe that error is due to using a non-static array and a common solution to this problem is using three-argument version of `jax.numpy.where()`.

How can i implement the logic of the lambda function in terms of the JIT-compatible three-argument version of `jax.numpy.where()`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the fact that `y = x[x > 0]` returns an array whose size depends on the values within `x`; another way of saying this is that `y` has a dynamic shape. JAX's transform model does not currently support dynamically-shaped arrays, and the result is the error you see.

Typically you can work around this by re-expressing your computation so that it does not rely on constructing dynamically-shaped intermediate arrays. In this case something like the following should work:

```py
lambda_operation = lambda x: jnp.where(x > 0, x, 0.0).sum() / (x > 0).sum()
```